# name conflict in recursive method in trait

Tags: php, laravel, class, recursion, traits

i'm using two traits including methods with same name,
one of them is recursive,
and when it calls itself name conflict happens.

**no Exception has been throwed, it calls the method in trait B.**

```
trait A
{
    private function method()
    {
        $this->method();
    }
}

trait B
{
    private function method()
    {
    }
}
class myClass
{
    use A, B
    {
        B::method insteadOf A;
        A::method as A_method;
    }
}
```

i know i can do this `$this->A_method();` in trait A but,
i'm also using these traits in other classes.


Any idea other than reversing my aliases (method in trait B might become recursive too)?

Comment: Are there any namespaces defined for each one of them?

Comment: @Sachin Bahukhandi
 yes, there are.i checked them already. it's not throwing error LINE 3 OF THE QUESTION